# UWP/WinRT: GetKeyState returning unexpected values

Tags: win-universal-app, c++-cx

I'm using the following code to read the key state of the `Ctrl` key:

```
void OnKeyDown(Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::KeyRoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    auto ctrlState = Core::CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread()->GetKeyState(VirtualKey::Control);

    //Debug code:
    int ctrlInt = (int)ctrlState;
    auto inputText = "\nctrlState is: " + ctrlInt + "\n";
    auto wstringText = std::wstring(inputText->Data());
    OutputDebugString(wstringText.c_str());
```

Based on the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.getkeystate.aspx), I would expect that calling `GetKeyState` would return one of three possible values from the enumeration `CoreVirtualKeyStates` - None (0), Down (1), Locked (2).

However, what I'm getting is very different from the debug code. Whenever a key is pressed and `Ctrl` is not pressed, it is outputting 2. Every other time `Ctrl` is pressed, it is outputting alternatively 1 or 3.

3 is not even a value in this enumeration, and `Ctrl` should not be able to be locked as there is no equivalent to `CapsLock`. Also, I don't see why alternating presses should be returning different values.

What's going on here?

Comment: It is a bit-field value, a key can be both down *and* "locked".  Compare to the ::GetKeyState() function.  That the Ctrl key is not a "toggle" key like Capslock is not relevant.  You have to use the & operator to test for the Down state.

Comment: @HansPassant What does it mean for Ctrl key to be locked given there is no Ctrllock key to lock it down?

Comment: It means whatever you like it to mean.  Could be useful to design UI for people with an impairment that makes it hard to press two keys at the same time for example.  But do beware that there is no LED on the keyboard that indicates its state so if you use it then you have to display its state on your UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though result is not as described in the documentation, 3 should be a combination value, equal to Down|Locked So you can just ignore the Locked flag and check the Down flag:

```
void OnKeyDown(Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::KeyRoutedEventArgs^ e) {
    auto ctrlState = Core::CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread()->GetKeyState(VirtualKey::Control);
    bool isControlPressed = (ctrlState & Core::CoreWindow::CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down) == Core::CoreWindow::CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down;
}
```

Or you can use [GetKeyStateAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.getasynckeystate.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which works as described in the documentation:

```
void OnKeyDown(Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::KeyRoutedEventArgs^ e) {
    auto ctrlState = Core::CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread()->GetKeyStateAsync(VirtualKey::Control);
    bool isControlPressed = ctrlState == Core::CoreWindow::CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down;
}
```

It doesn't exactly answer the question but I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I'll go ahead and just test for Down as a flag, as it works. Using GetKeyStateAsync seems like it wouldn't work for my application, as I'm implementing hot keys: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/11/30/272262.aspx (old article but presumably still applicable)